# How to play protected video content in iOS using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone

I have used the below implementation to play a protected video content from the media server, but it shows play icon with cross line.

After login app need to sync the cookies to the media assets to play the protected video after authentication.
By using AVURLAsset, we are streaming the protected video but its not working.

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
NSDictionary *opt = @{
                           AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey: @(AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidRemoteReferenceToLocal),
                           AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey: cookies
                      };
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:linkUrl//Media protected URL(http://www.example.com/media/video/media_mp4)
                                         options:opt];

AVPlayerItem * item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
AVPlayerViewController *playerVC = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
playerVC.player = player;

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.6 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:playerVC animated:NO completion:nil];        
});
```

Comment: What kind of protected video ? DRM ?

Comment: Its not DRM, but it requires single sign on authentication which already got from the login service.

Comment: You need to explain how does the authentication apply on the video. If someone obtains the direct link of the media, will it be able to play the video? or the link is generated based on the authentication result, and will expire some time later? we need a lot more details before we can help.

Comment: In our app first we hit the login service with user name and password for login. After login we able to get the cookies from NSHTTPCookieStorage, to play the protected media again we hit the media URL along with the cookies sync. The only way to authenticate the media URL is to sync the cookies. Its was working fine in when I load the media URL as NSURLRequest in a UIWebView, but from iOS 10 specifically its not working. We checked with the native safari browser and its also not working. Then we decided to use native controls like AVPlayer to achieve the same.

Answer (score 4):

After searching a lot and finally it worked for me. I got the app cookies from `NSHTTPCookieStorage` class. Then using this I created a dictionary with key value pairs as below,
`@{AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey : cookies}`

Then I set this dictionary to the options in the `AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:linkUrl` options:

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];

AVURLAsset * asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:linkUrl options:@{AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey : cookies}];

AVPlayerItem * item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];

AVPlayerViewController *playerVC = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];

playerVC.player = player;

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.6 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self presentViewController:playerVC animated:NO completion:nil];

});
```

Comment: @Dipen Panchasara, It's not working for me :( . I am using this in swift language.

Comment: @PallaviNikumbh i have not tried on swift but for Objective-C it works. It would be good you put your code.

Comment: @PallaviNikumbh you can phrase your problem and put it as SO question. it would be good and it will reach to SO community to answer.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I have put my question. Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899128/how-to-play-video-with-cookies-content-in-ios-using-avplayer

Comment: @PallaviNikumbh will look into it